# Fix external screen resolution Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I've got an external screen that works fine and my machine detects it's resolution properly, but I've extended this monitor with an external cable and this is the problem:

The maximum screen resolution became 1024x768 and adding a new resolution using `cvt` and `xrandr` doesn't solve the problem, it creates a gap between the main display and the external display that is invisible! and there is an empty space at the end of the external display that I can't reach.

There is an answer that recommends using `cvt -r` to solve the problem of the unreachable part of the external display but it doesn't remove the gap between the main display and the external display.

The maximum external display resolution is 1280x1024.

EDIT:

The output of xrandr

```
$xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2390 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
LVDS-1-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768      60.05*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
VGA-1-1 connected 1024x768+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: what is your primary display resolution?

Comment: @pratap 1366x768

Comment: i understood that your primary display is 1366x768 and your external display is 1280x1024. Is there any adapter between the motherboard and the external monitor? or is it directly connected with HDMI or VGA or DVI Cable without any adapters? In Settings>Devices>Displays what is selected? "Join Displays" or "Mirror" or "Single Display" ?

Comment: There is a cable that connects to the VGA adapter to make it accept two monitors instead of one, currently I am connecting only one to that cable. I am joining the displays

Comment: can you paste the output of `xrandr` in your Question.

Comment: can you add the resolution 1366x768 to your VGA adapter output and see?

Comment: the maximum resolution is missing may be due to the primary display height is 768 (1366x768) and that's why it is limited to adjacent screen with same height 768 (1024x768)

Comment: No, The maximum display will be present and activated if I connected the external monitor to the VGA adapter directly without the cable.

Comment: Yes, you are rite. Adapter Could be the problem here.

Comment: Yeah, But it's really annoying that it works fine on windows 10.

Comment: hum.. i got a clue that if you see the VGA-1-1 connected 1024x768+1366+0 it is extending upto 1024 in horizontal and the actual resolution is 1280. May be this is the empty place at the end of the screen.

Comment: can you try this command, i am not with my laptop and monitor to test this `xrandr --output VGA-1-1 --rate 60 --mode 1024x768 --fb 1280x1024 --panning 1280x1024` if something goes wrong just logout or reboot. it will not be saved.

Comment: it gives an error 
`xrandr: specified screen 1280x1024 not large enough for output VGA-1-1 (1024x768+1366+0)
xrandr: specified screen 1280x1024 not large enough for output LVDS-1-1 (1366x768+0+0)`

Comment: thats fine, this adaptor may be limiting it to  (1024x768). Have you tried adding mode 1280x1024 to VGA-1-1 out put before?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79349/discussion-between-xayden-rosario-and-pratap).

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the VGA cable, I thought it should make two displays but instead, it was doubling the display, so that might be the issue.