# New Thinkpad with fresh Ubuntu installed over Windows, the USB-c dock no longer works for display output

Tags: external-monitor

I have a brand new ThinkPad and just got Ubuntu installed and updated. I got the USB-C dock too and everything has been amazing and seamless (thank you Ubuntu!), except from the fact that the dock display output does not work.

In the Ubuntu display menu, the external monitor does show up, just like it should, but the screen remains black and the monitor does not "see" the laptop.

Oddly, when first setting it up it did work for a second, but was for some reason set to the lowest resolution (like 600x300 or something). When I went to the settings menu to change it to the native resolution, it flickered and then disconnected, never to reconnect again.

HDMI works fine and that's what I currently use (I know, my problem is not a real problem).

Here is the output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
   1920x1080     60.01 +  60.01*   59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32                                                                                     
   512x384       60.00                                                                                                                
   512x288       60.00    59.92                                                                                                       
   480x270       59.63    59.82                                                                                                       
   400x300       60.32    56.34                                                                                                       
   432x243       59.92    59.57                                                                                                       
   320x240       60.05                                                                                                                
   360x202       59.51    59.13                                                                                                       
   320x180       59.84    59.32                                                                                                       
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                                                                          
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                                                                        
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                                                                          
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                                                                        
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                                                                        
DP-1-2 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm                                            
   3840x2160     30.00                                                                                                                
   2560x1440     59.95                                                                                                                
   1920x1080     60.00*   59.94                                                                                                       
   1600x900      60.00                                                                                                                
   1280x1024     60.02                                                                                                                
   1280x800      59.81                                                                                                                
   1152x864      59.97                                                                                                                
   1280x720      60.00    59.94                                                                                                       
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
DP-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: can you paste the output of `xrandr`

Comment: I tried rotating the display and after about 5 minutes it turned on! Rotated it back and it shut back off, now it is stuck off again ???

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049615/fix-external-screen-resolution-xubuntu-18-04#comment1713749_1049615 with the display adapters some issues are there.